# how do i get turtle(rocket) to chase my other turtle(spaceship)?

Tags: python

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')

spaceship = Turtle()
spaceship.color('red')
spaceship.penup()

speed = 1

def travel():
    spaceship.forward(speed)
    wn.ontimer(travel, 10)

wn.onkey(lambda: spaceship.setheading(90), 'Up')
wn.onkey(lambda: spaceship.setheading(180), 'Left')
wn.onkey(lambda: spaceship.setheading(0), 'Right')
wn.onkey(lambda: spaceship.setheading(270), 'Down')

while True:
    spaceship.forward(speed)
    if spaceship.xcor() > 500:
        spaceship.goto (-500,0)
    elif spaceship.ycor() > 500:
        spaceship.goto(0,-500)
wn.listen()

travel()

wn.mainloop()
```

after i put the while true function in the keyboard movement stopped working.

I'm trying to get my keyboard function to work but after i put the while true function in it stopped working.

Comment: The 'while True' loop never ends, thus the last 3 lines of codes will never be executed. Either try to put the while loop after the last list of code, or integrate it into the main loop somehow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.